# My bluetooth headphone aren't getting detected in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I have Infinity Glide 510 Bluetooth headphones and when I try and connect them it does not even get detected by Ubuntu 20.04. I have tried everything, like putting the headphones into pairing mode, restarting the system and even reinstalling the bluez package. Recently I had connected Second Gen Airpods, and they worked fine. My Infinty glides aren't even being discovered by Ubuntu.